# getting the following error "Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() "

Tags: php, xml

What do I have wrong here? Getting an error for the 2nd line (foreach....) Can someone please help me correct it?   UPDATE: I think my problem is the XML file is not loading. Ill need to correct that first.

```
 $xml = simplexml_load_string($result);              

    foreach($xml->statusCode as $statusCode){
            if($statusCode != '200'){
                echo $failureMessage; 
                echo 'Error: <span class="formerror">'; 
                echo $xml->errorMessage;                
                echo '</span>';
            } else {
                echo $successMessage. 
                '<ul>
                    <li>First Name: '.$c['f_name'].'</li>
                    <li>Last Name: '.$c['l_name'].'</li>
                    <li>Your Zipcode: '.$c['zipcode'].'</li>
                    <li>Your Email: '.$c['email'].'</li>
                    <li>Your Phone Number: '.$c['phone'].'</li>';
                if($c['comments'] != ''){ 
                    echo '<li>'.$c['comments'].'</li></ul>';
                } else {
                    echo '</ul>';
                }
                ?>
```

Comment: did you try below answer?

Answer (score 0):

> getting the following error “Warning: Invalid argument supplied for
>   foreach() ”

Its because of either `null` or `false`

```
foreach($xml->statusCode as $statusCode){ 
             ^
            see var_dump($xml->statusCode), 
            since $xml is either null or false you get above error
```

We can regenerate this error like this for example

```
$ php -r 'foreach(null as $e){}'
PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in Command line code on line 1

/*false OR FALSE*/
$ php -r 'foreach(false as $e){}'
PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in Command line code on line 1
```

So you need error handling first

```
if ($xml === FALSE) 
{
    throw new Exception('Failed to load XML string.');
}else
{ 
     foreach($xml->statusCode as $statusCode)
     { 
             /* Remaining code goes here */
     }
}
```